# How do I construct a LINESTRING by aggregating Points (ST_MakeLine) in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, spatial

Let's say I have a table with 3 points,

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( id int PRIMARY KEY, geog point );
INSERT INTO foo (id, geog) VALUES
  ( 1, Point(0,0) ),
  ( 2, Point(1,1) ),
  ( 3, Point(2,2) );
```

How can I construct a `LINESTRING` with those three points in those three different rows. The resulting WKT should be `LINESTRING( 0 0, 1 1, 2 2 )`?

---

PostGIS does this with a Spatial Aggregate called [`ST_MakeLine`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.5/ST_MakeLine.html)

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(geog)
FROM foo
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because MariaDB (and MySQL) lack all spatial aggregates, the only method is currently to create the WKT, and force MySQL to parse that WKT.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
  ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT(
    'LINESTRING (',
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(ST_X(geog),' ',ST_Y(geog)) SEPARATOR ','),
    ')'
  ))
)
FROM foo
ORDER BY id;
-- returns LINESTRING (0 0,1 1,2 2)
```

The inside part

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(ST_X(geog),' ',ST_Y(geog)) SEPARATOR ',')
```

Creates the point list, and then we just wrap that in `LINESTRING ( $pointlist )` and feed that to [`ST_GeomFromText()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-linestring-property-functions.html)

---

*ℹ There are [type-specific versions of `ST_GeomFromText`, but at least in MariaDB they seem to do nothing different, except add confusion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/227715/2639).*