# Do the type-specific WKT- constructors function differently from ST_GeomFromText?

Tags: mariadb, spatial, mariadb-10.3

From the docs on MariaDB, for [`ST_LineStringFromText`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/st_linefromtext/)

> **Constructs a `LINESTRING` value** using its WKT representation and SRID.
>
> `ST_LineFromText()`, `ST_LineStringFromText()`, `ST_LineFromText()` and `ST_LineStringFromText()` are all synonyms.

It seems to be technically incorrect though, for example here we construct a point and a polygon using `ST_LineStringFromText()`,

```
WITH t(geom) AS ( VALUES
  (ST_LineStringFromText('POLYGON ((35 10, 45 45, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10),(20 30, 35 35, 30 20, 20 30))')),
  (ST_LineStringFromText('POINT( 0 0 )')),
  (ST_LineStringFromText('LINESTRING( 0 0, 1 1 )'))
)
SELECT ST_AsText(geom)
FROM t;
```

Returns..

```
POLYGON((35 10,45 45,15 40,10 20,35 10),(20 30,35 35,30 20,20 30))
POINT(0 0)
LINESTRING(0 0,1 1)
```

The Polygon functions are just as confusingly documented,

> **Constructs a `POLYGON` value** using its WKT representation and SRID.
>
> `ST_PolyFromText()`, `ST_PolygonFromText()`, `PolyFromText()` and `ST_PolygonFromText()` are all synonyms.

Yet you can replace `ST_LineStringFromText` with `ST_PolyFromText` and they work the same way.

## MySQL Behavior

With MySQL 8 you seem to get an error on the above construction,

> WKT value is a geometry of unexpected type `POINT` in `st_linestringfromtext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However cute and undocumented, all these functions [map internally to `Create_func_geometry_from_text` in `item_create.cc`,](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/2ccae65cff59c0e65402291ca7eb52caa6d152fd/sql/item_create.cc). For this reason, I would advise using [`ST_GeomFromText()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/st_geomfromtext/) which best reflects that.

```
GEOMCOLLFROMTEXT
GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONFROMTEXT
GEOMETRYFROMTEXT
GEOMFROMTEXT
LINEFROMTEXT
LINESTRINGFROMTEXT
MLINEFROMTEXT
MPOINTFROMTEXT
MPOLYFROMTEXT
MULTILINESTRINGFROMTEXT
MULTIPOINTFROMTEXT
MULTIPOLYGONFROMTEXT
POINTFROMTEXT
POLYFROMTEXT
POLYGONFROMTEXT
ST_GEOMCOLLFROMTEXT
ST_GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONFROMTEXT
ST_GEOMETRYFROMTEXT
ST_GEOMFROMTEXT
ST_LINEFROMTEXT
ST_LINESTRINGFROMTEXT
ST_MLINEFROMTEXT
ST_MPOINTFROMTEXT
ST_MPOLYFROMTEXT
ST_MULTILINESTRINGFROMTEXT
ST_MULTIPOINTFROMTEXT
ST_MULTIPOLYGONFROMTEXT
ST_POINTFROMTEXT
ST_POLYFROMTEXT
ST_POLYGONFROMTEXT
```