# Does MySQL or MariaDB support a LineString constructor that takes points?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, spatial, mysql-8.0

It seems with MySQL and MariaDB I'm getting the following when I try to use the LineString constructor. In [PostGIS I can do this with `ST_MakeLine(pt1,pt2)`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html)

```
> SELECT ST_MakeLine(Point(0,0), Point(0,1));
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION ST_MakeLine does not exist

> SELECT ST_LineString(Point(0,0), Point(0,1));
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION ST_LineString does not exist
```

Is the only way to construct a [`LINESTRING` to use `ST_GeomFromText` or `ST_LineFromText`, or `ST_LineStringFromText`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/227715/2639)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as a general rule the constructors for MySQL are only available with non-`ST_` prefixes.

So you'll want [`LineString(pt1,pt2)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_linestring)

```
SELECT LineString(Point(0,0), Point(0,1));
```